# Does a set belongs to a set of numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I the following sets: $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and a set $B=\{2\}$. Is the following statement correct: $B \in A $?

Comment: $2$ is an element of $A$, but not $B$. Instead $B\subset A$.

Comment: The title of your question gives rise to the intrinsic question: "what exactly *is* a number? "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Every element of $A$ is a number, whereas $B$ is not a number. Therefore, you cannot possibly have $B\in A$.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a set as a box that might contain some items.  So, $A$ is a box containing the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ and $B$ is a box containing just $2$.  You can have sets within sets so boxes within boxes (think of Amazon parcels).  So, a set containing $B$ is possible e.g. $\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}$ but $A$ is not such a set so in this case $B$ is not a member of $A$.  It is not the question asked but $B$ is a subset of $A$ which means that everything in $A$ is also in $B$.  There is a subtle but important difference here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if and only if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

- $1=\{2\}$
- $3=\{2\}$
- $4=\{2\}$
- $5=\{2\}$

But most probably you work in a context where this is not the case.

So the answer to your question is most probably: "no".

Also note that $2=\{2\}$ is not mentioned as condition. This because this condition is *automatically* not satisfied if the axiom of regularity is accepted. This axiom forbids e.g. that $2\in 2$.